# Display Kusto query results as chart

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have an Azure AppInsights dashboard.
One item on the dashboard is a Kusto query and its results are always displayed as a table. 
Is there a way to display the results as a chart on the dashboard?

Comment: there is a chart button, please click that button -> then select pin to dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In application insights -> logs, after you run the query, there is a `chart` button. You can click the `chart` button, and you can also customize the chart via "chart formatting" -> then select "pin to dashboard":

[image]

Another way is that you can directly use [render operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) in your query, then pin the chart to dashboard.

Comment: @Dan, what do you mean it does not work? some errors?

Comment: or you can use [render operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) in your query.

Comment: Using the render operator AND removing the query and re-adding it to the dashboard solved the problem. Please edit your answer to include the comment about the "render operator". I'll already mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: @Dan, added it in the answer:).